# In GCP, I deleted a project that had a bucket. How can I reuse the bucket name in a different project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, cloud, storage, bucket

In Google Cloud Platform, I used a bucket name in a project. I had to delete the project. When I tried to use the same bucket name in a new project, it says "That bucket name is taken. Try another."
How can I reuse the bucket name? I used the bucket name for my own website, so the bucket name was like [www.blah.com](http://www.blah.com). The domain name was registered with google and it is still registered, but I cannot make it active since GCP does not allow me to reuse the bucket name.
Thanks.

Comment: I cannot find a reference, but I believe you must wait 30 days for the old bucket name to become available. I recommend contacting Google Cloud Support (paid) if you need access sooner.

Comment: My understanding is that bucket names have to be globally unique.  If you created a bucket under the auspices of a project then if you delete the project, don't the resources of that project get "held" ... you have some grace period before the project's resources are actually deleted.  Maybe you have to explicitly delete the bucket from the project before deleting the project to release the bucket.

Comment: @Kolban You can undelete projects for IIRC 30 days. That is where I think I get the number of days before a bucket name becomes available again.

Answer (score 2):

You can restore the deleted project as per this project [restore](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects?visit_id=637449536005264823-1949069424&rd=1#restoring_a_project) process, then delete the [bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-buckets) using the gcloud command:

```
gcloud projects undelete PROJECT_ID
```

```
gsutil rm -r gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

Once you delete the bucket from the project you can reuse the name for new bucket on another project.

Please note that, Project owners can restore a deleted project within the 30-day recovery period; however, Cloud Storage resources are deleted before the 30-day period ends.

Comment: Many thanks for all the help. I decided to delete the project since it had an App Engine that I could not delete. It still uses storages and I had monthly charges for the storage. The spec says that I can completely delete the App Engine only by deleting the project. I will probably wait for 30 days, after which I'll see if I can use the bucket name again.